# Saltos de linea en textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

En mi html creo un textarea. En mi Javascript llamo al valor y finalmente a ese valor lo imprimo en Whatsapp. Problema: cuando hago un salto de linea en el textarea se muestra, pero en el WhatsApp se muestra todo en una linea. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow! No es fácil ayudarte cuando no escribes ningún código.
Tal vez puedes hacer algo como `texto.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n')`. Pero no se si el texto solo es texto o HTML.

Comment: proba insertar el char de newline `%0a`

Comment: Se hace como dice @aloMalbarez (%0A), pero también depende de como pases este texto. Si pones el código o parte de (con el que estas intentando), te podremos ayudar mucho mas rápido.